# wordpress website running really slow in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, wordpress, plugins, loading

I have got a serious problem with one of our websites in IE.
http://platformgastvrijezorg.nl/beta

It runs really fast in FF and chrome, but as stated terribly slow in IE7+, +10 seconds.
We dont support IE6.

We tried about everything... gzip, minifying js, etc. but nothing seems to help.
Our deadline is in 2 days, so any help would be appreciated much!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made sure that the javascript is not causing problems in IE? IE6 is known to crash on certain scripts.

Comment: Hei When your site is viewed in IE6 its showing some static block saying to visit the site in FF, Chrome and ..... Then how can we see the diff in loading time?

Comment: That is true, we dont support IE6. Forgot to state that, sorry. So it is IE7+

Comment: Try adding expiry cache headers for images, your site has too many images for the home page itself. And any browser handles simultaneous requests upto a level. So if u can try to compress the images.. http://tools.pingdom.com/tools/?url=http://platformgastvrijezorg.nl/beta&treeview=0&column=loadtime&order=1&type=1&save=true see whether any of these requests can be deleted!

Comment: we do use a caching plugin, allthough it is off right now for testing purposes. Even when that is on, the site still is really slow.
If you take a look at pingdom, you will see that the images are really small, so that shouldnt be the problem either.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess at the Cufon text replacement. But really the best way to tell is to take out one bit of functionality at a time and see if the problem is fixed. Then you'll know what the culprit is.

Try disabling all JS, then put it back and disable all CSS. This should help narrow things down, from there you can try removing progressively smaller chunks of functionality until you've found the problem.

It's a boring answer and you'll need to be methodical but you'll find the problem.

Comment: I'll second this — I've seen sites slow down a fair bit in IE when using Cufon. Rather than disabling all the JS and CSS to start with, try disabling Cufon only and see what effect that has.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like @edeverett said, also you have a lot of http request, you should at least combine your js and css files if it's possible.